# Capture the wool sign ups

Tags: discussion, game-on

> **UPDATE: It has again been moved to the 18th (at the same time) due to
>   a low turn out for the Saturday.**

Following the <strike>rousing success</strike> failure of our [last Minecraft game on!](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLD6F6C73733296805) we have decided to have another go! The map will be another of Vechs’ super hostile maps by the name of [Capture the wool](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/191908-ctmcollection-%E2%98%A0-vechs-super-hostile-series-%E2%98%A0/#AnchorCapture1). The map is designed for 8 to 12 players, but after looking at the map I see no reason not to allow more players if there is a high enough demand.

The event will take place at [19:00 UTC](http://time.is/19:00_in_England) on the 18th of December and if you would like to play leave an answer to this question. We will be playing on mine.stackgaming.com courtesy of Marco Ceppi

**Skins**

Your skin must either be red or blue. If you can, try to have one of each as it allows flexibility with the teams. But if you have a preference please state it in your answer. If you do not have a suitable skin you may use these:

[image: Preview of skins]
[image: Red skin][image: Blue skin]

**Filming**

I will be filming this event and it will go on our [YouTube channel](http://www.youtube.com/user/GamingSE/). If you want to and have the ability to film it then please say in your answer as it would nice to have videos from each team's point of view.

**Voice talk**

For this event we will be using [Mumble](http://mumble.sourceforge.net/) to communicate. Please install this even if you don’t have a microphone as you can still hear what everyone else is saying. Our server is mumble.stackgaming.com

**Teams**

Red:

- Ronan
- Wipqozn
- John
- Dave McClelland
- Murgatroid99

Blue:

- Fredy31
- DMA57361
- Ben blank
- Alexanderpas
- Thomas McDonald

Comment: I didn't really keep up with the other one, but from what I overheard, I highly suggest that you try to have 3-6 substitutes (depending on how many people sign up) so if someone doesn't show up/shows up late, the game can continue on.  I would love to participate, but not if it becomes some scheduling nightmare or delayed for hours.

Comment: If I didn't have plans for this specific time frame (7pm UTC - ? on the 17th) I'd be all over this...

Comment: @IanPugsley Why the question mark, that _is_ the time.

Comment: From 7pm UTC until question mark.

Comment: Wait the 16th is a friday. And on EST its 2PM. I'll be working. Thought you meant the sunday 18th.

Comment: So, it's Team Gaming vs. Team Stack Exchange, eh?

Comment: @GraceNote No it's just those logos are red and blue and we already decided they'd be the teams.

Comment: I would love to play, but please pick a day I can do in future!

Comment: @fredley We've been playing Minecraft for 3 out of every 4 Sundays at 1900 UTC.  This Sunday is the one week we're playing something different, so stay tuned to [the schedule](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3561/game-on-restructured) for the next time we're playing.

Comment: @RonanForman Can you accept something so that community stops bumping this? Perhaps add an answer with a link to the video and accept that?

Answer (score 1):

I would really like to try this, and I will probably be able to make it now that it's on Saturday (and the day after my last final). I have never done anything like this before (only SSP) so I don't know how much help I will be.

Comment: You don't need to be very experience with Minecraft at all. Just come along and have fun!

Comment: Would it be possible for you to make it either the day after or the day before? (at the same time)

Comment: @RonanForman I would not be able to make it on the day before (I will be in an airplane), but the day after should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Now being the 18th, I can make it.

But will we decide teams on the go or before? (for skin colors)
And even if its at 7PM UTC (2PM EST) please, show up early because we would like to start at 2. not at 4.

Posting my old answer.

I shall be playing as well.

I shall have those link skins.

[image: Redside][image: Blue side]

Comment: Are you going to be filming the event, I gather you have some method of doing so from the looks of your credit video.

Comment: I shall. I'll try to record voice at the same time. We'll see that in Mumble Sunday.

Answer (score 0):

To make it easier I will post to say that I will be playing.

Answer (score 0):

I will be playing as well.

INSERT MORE CHARACTERS HERE: :(

I am Wipqozn and [I approve this message](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2625882#2625882).

I will be using one of [these](http://www.minecraftskins.info/megaman.html) [skins](http://www.minecraftskins.info/zero.html):

[image]

[image]

Comment: TF2 skins could help

Comment: *INSERT MORE CHARACTERS HERE* `<-` Tempting!

Comment: Mmm, green nipples.

Answer (score 0):

I'd love to take part too, the last one was good fun!

However, I *might* not be able to make 19:00 UTC sharp on the 16th. How'd you feel about late joiners -- maybe arrange teams etc before starting so I could jump in 15mins late if necessary..?

Comment: We need to arrange teams before hand due to the different skins or each team, so that should be fine.

Comment: Lovely, I'll start hacking a red and blue hat (and maybe the shirt emblems) on to my current skin in preparation...

Comment: @DMA57361 the time has been changed back to the 17th

Comment: @Wipqozn That'll work; whatever date/time you guys pick I'll try to be there. :)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like fun!  Count me in.

[image: skin preview]

(Apologies for the crappy render, I don't normally use a previewer!)

Comment: Would it be possible for you to make it either the day after or the day before? (at the same time)

Comment: @Ronan Forman — I could make the 18th, but not the 16th; I'd be at work.

Answer (score 0):

I should be able to make it.  Count me in